# C# Incremented Array Number

Tags: c#, arrays, numbers, increment

Okay, lets assume we have a variable with an array like this

```
int[] digit;
int x = 5; 
for(int i=0;i < = 5; i++)
{ digit[i] = 0;}
```

All value array on var Digit have 0. So what i want to do its i want to increment the value on that digit from right using **Button Control** that adds increment (that means digit[4] to digit[3] and so on) and when the value hits certain number example 5 in digit[4], it would come back to value 0 and the next var digit incremented (digit[3]). And the incremented start again and so on.

I already try using if and switch to make this happen like this

```
private btnClick_Click(Object Sender, Event Args)
{
     digit[4] +=1;
     if(digit[4] > 5) { digit[3] += 1;}
     if(digit[3] > 5) { digit[2] += 1;}
     //and so on
     switch(digit[4])
     {
         case 5: digit[4]=0;
     }
     //and so on
}
```

But its only for logic *If We Know The Array Number Location*. Say if i retrieve that number for somewhere like 15 digit. If we set array number so little on that **command Button**, it cannot fill the array right?

Imma already confused thinking this, any suggestion, help, discussion ill appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "if we know the array number location"? Why can't you just keep that as a private field in the class?

Comment: This looks like a homework trying teach you some programming logic...  Why should we obstruct your learning giving an answer?

Comment: Your question is really difficult to undestand. Apart from that, `i <= 5` will make the `for` loop fail with an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. It would be helpful to include executable code and a clear description of your problem.

Comment: @RMH yes thats the logic. Why i need the backwards array bcus my programming project retrieve the string and converted to int. String like number 15152 for example. And after the operation it would become 15283.  So that means 2 its digit[4]

Comment: Also note that `new int[5]` creates an array with every element set to 0 to start with, so your initial loop is pointless.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes i know that. Every new all element becomes 0, that is why i would do increment when i get that numbers.

Comment: @p3tch i am using an array and called the element number depends from database and sometimes the number digit length can be vary like 12000 or maybe 1200000

Comment: So if you know that, why have you got the loop setting everything to 0 immediately after creating the array? (A broken loop at that, given that it'll throw an exception.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet i will edited, moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to increment by one, and not any substraction or increment by let's say 5, I'd use a simple solution like this:

```
private void btnClick_Click(Object Sender, Event Args) {
    int maxValue = 5;
    int carry = 1; // This is our increment

    // iterate through your digits back to front
    for(int i = digit.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        digit[i] += carry;  // increase the value by the carry. This will at least increment the last digit by one
        carry = 0;

        // if we reach our max value, we set the carry to one to add it to the next digit, and reset our current digit to 0.
        // If you wanted to increase by more than 1 a time, we would have to add some more calculations here as it would
        // be incorrect to just reset digit[i] to 0.
        if(digit[i] >= maxValue) {
            carry = 1; // the next digit will now be told to increase by one - and so forth
            digit[i] = 0;
        } else {
            break; // This will break out of the for - loop and stop processing digits as everything just fit nicely and we don't have to update more previous digits
        }
    }
}
```

Not that once you reach `44444` and increment, you will end up with `00000`.

Comment: Why keep iterating when carry is 0? Just break out of the loop at that point.

Comment: Ah, sure! @JonSkeet

Comment: i was also thinking like that too, using subtraction on loop. i will trying that. Thanks for your idea @habegage